# replace in microsoft frontpage

Tags: string, search, replace, frontpage

hello
i want to replace between right and left in my doc

for example frontpage searches left and replace with right and searches right and replace it with left
so :
right >>> left
left >>> right

i think i need to regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply first replace right with for ex "right_temp" then replace "left" with "right". Then replache "right_temp" with left.